# Differential equations - Relation between the number of solutions and the order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The case $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$:**

I want to show that in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ each differential equation has a solution.

I have done the following:

Each element of the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ is of the form $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n α_kz^{d_k}e^{β_kz}}$.

A differential equation in this ring is of the form $$Ly = \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{l=1}^n C_lz^{d_l} e^{\beta_l z} , \ \ \alpha_k , \beta_l \in \mathbb{C} \ \ \ \ (*)$$

At the linear differential equations we can apply the superposition principle. That means that we can split the problem $(*)$ into the subproblems $$Ly(z)=0, \ \ Ly(z)=C_lz^{d_l} e^{\beta_l z}, \ \ l=1, 2, \dots , n$$ so into an homogeneous and $n$ non-homogeneous equations. We solve these equations and then we add the solution of the homogeneous $y_{H}(z)$ and the solutions $y_{p_i}(z)$of the $n$ non-homogeneous equations. 
So we get the general solution of the equation $(*)$, which is $$y(z)=y_{H}(z)+\sum_{l=1}^n y_{p_i}(z)$$

To solve the homogeneous equation $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=0$$ we find the characteristic equation and its eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$.

- If $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$ are eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$, then the solution of $Ly(z)=0$ is $$y_{H}(z)=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i e^{\lambda_i z}.$$
- If $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalues of multiplicity $M>1$, then the $$e^{\lambda_i z}, ze^{\lambda_i z}, z^2e^{\lambda_i z}, \dots , z^{M-1}e^{\lambda_i z}$$ are $M$ linear independent solutions of $Ly(z)=0$.

To solve the equation $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=C_lz^{d_l} e^{\beta_l z} \ \ \ \ \ (**)$$ we do the following:

- If $\beta_l$ is not one of the eigenvalues:

  We suppose that the solution is in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$, so it is of the form $$y(z)=e^{\beta_l z} x(z)$$

  So $$y^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\beta_l^j e^{\beta_l z}x^{(k-j)}(z)$$

  Substituting in $(**)$ we get the following equation, the order of which is the same as the order of $(**)$, $$\sum_{k=0}^m \beta_k x^{(k)}(z)=C_lz^{d_l}$$

  The solution of the above equation will be polynomials.

  The first non-zero term $\beta_k$ determines the degree of $x$.

  For example if $\beta_o \neq 0$ then the solution will have degree at most $l$, and will be of the form $$x(z)=\gamma_l z^l +\dots +\gamma_0$$ 
  Then $$x'(z)=l\gamma_l z^{l-1}+\dots +\gamma_1 \\ \dots \\ x^{(l)}(z)=l!\gamma_l$$

  Then $$\sum_{k=0}^m \beta_k x^{(k)}(z)=C_lz^{d_l}  \Rightarrow \beta_o\gamma_kz^{d_l}+(\beta_0\gamma_{l-1}+l\gamma_la_1)z^{d_l-1}+ \dots =C_lz^{d_l} $$

  So it must stand $$\beta_0\gamma_l=C_l \Rightarrow \gamma_l=\frac{C_l}{\beta_0} \\ \beta_0\gamma_{l-1}+l\gamma_la_1=0 \\ \dots $$

  So to solve the differential equation we have to solve the above system.

> We write this in the form of matrix. Can we be sure that we will find an unique solution?
>
> In this ring the number of solutions is equal to the number of the order, right? How can we justify that?

- If $\beta_l$ is one of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, and the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $L$:

  We suppose that the solution is in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$, so it is of the form $$y(z)=z^L e^{\beta_l z} x(z)=e^{\beta_l z}\tilde{x}(z)$$ and we continue as in the previous case.

> Is everything correct?
>
> Could I improve something at the formulation?

---

**The case $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$**:

I want to check when in the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ a differential equation has a solution.

I have done the following:

Each element of the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ is of the form $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n α_ke^{β_kz}}$.

A differential equation in this ring is of the form $$Ly = \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{l=1}^n C_l e^{\beta_l z} , \ \ \alpha_k , \beta_l \in \mathbb{C} \ \ \ \ (*)$$

At the linear differential equations we can apply the superposition principle. That means that we can split the problem $(*)$ into the subproblems $$Ly(z)=0, \ \ Ly(z)=C_l e^{\beta_l z}, \ \ l=1, 2, \dots , n$$ so into an homogeneous and $n$ non-homogeneous equations. We solve these equations and then we add the solution of the homogeneous $y_{H}(z)$ and the solutions $y_{p_i}(z)$of the $n$ non-homogeneous equations. 
So we get the general solution of the equation $(*)$, which is $$y(z)=y_{H}(z)+\sum_{l=1}^n y_{p_i}(z)$$

To solve the homogeneous equation $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=0$$ we find the characteristic equation and its eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$.

- If $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$ are eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$, then the solution of $Ly(z)=0$ is $$y_{H}(z)=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i e^{\lambda_i z}.$$
- If $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalues of multiplicity $M>1$, then the $$e^{\lambda_i z}, ze^{\lambda_i z}, z^2e^{\lambda_i z}, \dots , z^{M-1}e^{\lambda_i z}$$ are $M$ linear independent solutions of $Ly(z)=0$. But in this case the solutions are not in $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$. So we reject this case.

To solve the equation $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=C_l e^{\beta_l z} \ \ \ \ \ (**)$$ we do the following:

- If $\beta_l$ is not one of the eigenvalues:

  We suppose that the solution is in the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$, so it is of the form $$y(z)=A_l e^{\beta_l z}$$

  So $$y^{(k)}(z)=\beta_l^k A_l e^{\beta_l z}$$

  Substituting in $(**)$ we get the following equation, the order of which is the same as the order of $(**)$, $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta_l^k A_l=C_l \Rightarrow A_l=\frac{C_l}{\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta_l^k}$$

  The solution of the above equation will be exponentials.
- If $\beta_l$ is one of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, and the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $L$:

  Then the solution is of the form $$y(z)=B_lz^Le^{\beta_l z}$$ but this is not an element of the ring. So we reject this case.

---

**The case $\mathbb{C}[z]$:**

I want to check when in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$ a differential equation has a solution.

I have done the following:

Each element of the ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$ is of the form $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n α_kz^{k}}$.

A differential equation in this ring is of the form $$Ly = \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{l=1}^n C_lz^{l}  , \ \ \alpha_k  \in \mathbb{C} \ \ \ \ (*)$$

At the linear differential equations we can apply the superposition principle. That means that we can split the problem $(*)$ into the subproblems $$Ly(z)=0, \ \ Ly(z)=C_lz^{l} , \ \ l=1, 2, \dots , n$$ so into an homogeneous and $n$ non-homogeneous equations. We solve these equations and then we add the solution of the homogeneous $y_{H}(z)$ and the solutions $y_{p_i}(z)$of the $n$ non-homogeneous equations. 
So we get the general solution of the equation $(*)$, which is $$y(z)=y_{H}(z)+\sum_{l=1}^n y_{p_i}(z)$$

To solve the homogeneous equation $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=0$$ we find the characteristic equation and its eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$.

- If $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$ are eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$, then the solution of $Ly(z)=0$ is $$y_{H}(z)=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i e^{\lambda_i z}.$$ 
  But then $y_{H} (z) \notin \mathbb{C}[z]$. So we reject this case.
- If $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalues of multiplicity $M>1$, then the $$e^{\lambda_i z}, ze^{\lambda_i z}, z^2e^{\lambda_i z}, \dots , z^{M-1}e^{\lambda_i z}$$ are $M$ linear independent solutions of $Ly(z)=0$. 
  The solutons are in $\mathbb{C}[z]$ only if $\lambda_i=0$.

To solve the equation $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=C_lz^{l}  \ \ \ \ \ (**)$$ we do the following:

- The multiplicity of $\lambda_i=0$ is $L$:

  We suppose that the solution is in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$, so it is of the form $$y(z)=z^L x(z)=\tilde{x}(z).$$

  So $$y^{(k)}(z)=\tilde{x}^{(k)}(z)$$

  Substituting in $(**)$ we get the following equation, the order of which is the same as the order of $(**)$, $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k  \tilde{x}^{(k)}(z)=C_lz^{l}$$

  The solution of the above equation will be polynomials.

  The first non-zero term $\alpha_k$ determines the degree of $\tilde{x}$.

  For example if $\alpha_0 \neq 0$ then the solution will have degree at most $l$, so $x$ will be at most $l-L$, and will be of the form $$x(z)=\gamma_l z^{l-L} +\dots +\gamma_0\Rightarrow \tilde{x}(z)=z^Lx(z)=\gamma_l z^{l} +\dots +\gamma_0 z^L$$ 
  Then $$\tilde{x}'(z)=l\gamma_l z^{l-1}+\dots +L\gamma_0z^{L-1} \\ \dots \\ \tilde{x}^{(l)}(z)=l!\gamma_l$$

  Then $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \tilde{x}^{(k)}(z)=C_lz^{d_l}  \Rightarrow \alpha_0\gamma_kz^{d_l}+ \dots =C_lz^{d_l} $$

  So it must stand $$\alpha_0\gamma_l=C_l \Rightarrow \gamma_l=\frac{C_l}{\alpha_0} \\ \dots $$

  So to solve the differential equation we have to solve the above system.

  So, a differential equation has a solution when the eigenvalues are $0$ and of multiplicity $>1$.

Comment: In principle yes, but you are missing a lot of complexity. It should be $\sum_{k=1}^n α_kz^{d_k}e^{β_kz}$ in the first line, that is, the degree depends on $k$ but is not $k$..

Comment: I edited it... So at the differential equation should it be also $$Ly = \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k y^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{l=1}^n z^{d_l} e^{\beta_l z} , \ \ \alpha_k , \beta_l \in \mathbb{C}$$ or is it correct as I have written it above? @LutzL

Comment: Yes, but why do you have all coefficients 1 on the right side?

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it? @LutzL

Comment: Yes, it looks better. But short of writing a computer implementation for the general case, the manual problems you can always solve from first principles without applying a general formula. I do not know if some minor detail is still wrong, the general approach is correct.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok... In this ring the number of solutions is equal to the number of the order, right? How can we justify that? @LutzL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $\mathbb{C}[z,e^{\lambda z} | \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ and when $\beta_l$ is not an eigenvalue, note that $\beta_0 = p(\beta_l) := \sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta_l^k$ ($\beta_0$ has a different meaning than $\beta_l$, which needs to be renamed IMO), where $p(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial. Since $\beta_l$ is not an eigenvalue, $\beta_0 \neq 0$ and $\deg x(z) = d_l$. So the coefficient matrix for the unknowns $\gamma_i$, is a $(d_l+1)\times(d_l+1)$ lower triangular matrix that has $\beta_0$ on the diagonals (the matrix came from the $d_l+1$ linear equations as a result of polynomial equality). Since the coefficient matrix is nonsingular, the values $\gamma_i$ can be determined uniquely.

In the case $\beta_l = \lambda_i$, degree of $x(z)$ is still $d_l$. Therefore, we have $L + d_l + 1$ equations, where first $L$ equations are already zero, because the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $L$. So the first nonzero coefficient is $\beta_L = c p^{(L)}(\beta_l)$ for some nonzero constant $c$. (Note $p^{(k)}(\beta_l) = 0$ for $k=0,1,\dots,L-1$). The remaining steps are the same as above.

(By the way, you need to select $y(z) = z^{L-1} e^{\beta_l z} x(z)$)

For the case $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} | \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ I think you need to explain why $\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta^k \neq 0$ before dividing.

For the case $\mathbb{C}[z]$, just select $\beta_l = 0$ in the first case. First consider the case when the characteristic polynomial has no $0$ roots. There are no homogenous solutions in the ring in this case. For nonhomogenous case $L y = z^{d_l}$, take the solution $y=\sum_{i=0}^{d_l} \gamma_i z^i$ and solve for $\gamma_i$ as in the previous case. If the characteristic polynomial has a $0$ root with multiplicity $M$, there are $M$ polynomial solutions for the homogenous equation, $1, z, \dots, z^{M-1}$. Now select $y=z^M \sum_{i=0}^{d_l} \gamma_i z^i$ and solve $M+d_l+1$ equations, where the first $M$ are already zero.

For all cases, the solution is unique for given initial conditions.

Comment: For the case $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z } \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ when $\lambda_i$ are roots of multiplicity $M>1$ we get that $e^{\lambda_i z}, ze^{\lambda_i z}, z^2e^{\lambda_i z}, \dots , z^{M-1}e^{\lambda_i z}$ are $M$ linear independent solutions of $Ly(z)=0$ and we said that in this case the solutions are not in the ring, but the first of these solutions is in the ring, or not?

Comment: The solutions to $Ly(z)=0$ is in the ring if and only if $M=1$. The solutions to $Ly(z)=e^{\beta z}$ is in the ring if and only if $M=1$ and $\beta$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: So at the case when $\lambda_i$ are roots of multiplicity $M>1$ the first solution of the $M$ linear independent solutions is $e^{\lambda_i z}$ which is an element of $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z } \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$, but we don't consider this solution because we can consider this to be a solution at the case when the multiplicty is $1$ ?

Comment: Also could you explain to me further the following part? $$$$ In the case $\beta_l = \lambda_i$, degree of $x(z)$ is still $d_l$. Therefore, we have $L + d_l + 1$ equations, where first $L$ equations are already zero, because the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $L$. So the first nonzero coefficient is $\beta_L = c p^{(L)}(\beta_l)$ for some nonzero constant $c$. (Note $p^{(k)}(\beta_l) = 0$ for $k=0,1,\dots,L-1$).

Comment: @MaryStar $e^{\lambda_i z}$ is a solution even if $M>1$. Other solutions of the form $z^k e^{\lambda_i z}$ are not in the ring, so we can safely ignore those. For the second question, which part you didn't understand?

Comment: So, do we say the following? $$$$  - If $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$ are roots of multiplicity $1$, then the solution of $Lx(z)=0$ is $$x_{H}(z)=\sum_{i=1}^mc_i e^{\lambda_i z}.$$ 
$$$$
 - If $\lambda_i$ is a root of multiplicity $M>1$, then the $$e^{\lambda_i z}, z e^{\lambda_i z}, z^2 e^{\lambda_i z}, \dots , z^{M-1} e^{\lambda_i z}$$ are $M$ linear independent solutions of $Lx(z)=0$ from which only the $e^{\lambda_i z}$ belongs to the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$.

Comment: Or could I improve something at the formulation?

Comment: I think it is good like this.

Comment: At the following part: $$$$ In the case $\beta_l = \lambda_i$, degree of $x(z)$ is still $d_l$. Therefore, we have $L + d_l + 1$ equations, where first $L$ equations are already zero, because the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $L$. So the first nonzero coefficient is $\beta_L = c p^{(L)}(\beta_l)$ for some nonzero constant $c$.$$$$ Do you mean that the degree of $x(z)$ is **at most** $d_l$? Then wouldn't the highest order at the left side be $d_l+L-1$ while at the right side the highest order is $d_l$? I don't really have understood the part: "where first $L$ equations are already zero".

Comment: It is due to the fact that $p^{(i)}(\lambda)=0, i=0,1,\dots,L-1$ if $\lambda$ has multiplicity $L$, i.e. $p(x) = (x - \lambda)^L q(x)$. When equating two polynomials, the coefficients of the unknowns are of the form $c_i p^{(i)}(\beta)$ for some nonzero $c_i$. Hence, when $\beta = \lambda_i$, the first $L$ equations will already be zero for both sides of the equation due to the previous fact. Try to do a simple example to see what I mean.

Comment: I think I have understood it now!! $$$$ For the case $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda z} | \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ is it always $\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta^k \neq 0$ ? Or can it also be that $\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta^k = 0$, so that we have to take cases?

Comment: If $\beta$ is a root of the polynomial, then the solution is not in the ring. So $\beta$ is not a root of the polynomial whenever a solution exists, which is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta^k \neq 0$.

Comment: So we have that $$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k \beta^k \neq 0$$ because $\beta$ is not an eigenvalue of the homogeneous equation, right?

Comment: Could you explain to me also why for the case $\mathbb{C}[z]$, the only feasible differential equations are of the form $\alpha_m y^{(m)}(z) = C_l z^{d_l}$ ? Why are all the other coefficients equal to zero?

Comment: I think I was wrong about that. Certainly there are polynomial solutions even if there are no zero roots in the characteristic polynomial. But I believe it can easily be fixable by selecting $\beta_l = 0$ in the first case. Anyway, I will update my answer.

Comment: When there are non zero roots in the characteristic polynomial isn't the solution then a combination of polynomials and exponentials?

Comment: Homogeneous solutions are like that. But forced solutions can be polynomial. Take for example $y'+y=z$, then one of the solution is $z-1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "forced solutions" ?

Comment: Some people say "forced solutions" to non-homogeneous solutions.

Comment: I got stuck right now... You say "selecting $\beta_l=0$ in the first case". Does in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$ the term $\beta_l$ exist?

Comment: @MaryStar I've updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I read now your edit about the polynomial ring. How can it be that a differential equation has only a solution of the nonhomogeneous equation, and not also a solution of the homogeneous equation?

Comment: It is because of the ring you work on.

Comment: Ok... Does this mean that a differential equation in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$ has always a solution?

Comment: In the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ does a differential equation have a particular solution only if $\beta_l$ is not one of the eigenvalues?

Comment: I found in my notes that the solutions of the non-homogeneous equation are of the form $e^{\beta_l z} (A_0+A_1z+…+A_{L}z^{L})$ and not $y(z)=B_lz^Le^{\beta_l z}$ when $\beta_l$ is a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation of multiplicity $L$. Which of them is correct? I got stuck right now...